# Adding a new row (with a templated column) to an Infragistics UltraWebGrid

Tags: asp.net, javascript, web-applications, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I am using the Infragistics UltraWebGrid to capture some data. I don't have this grid bound to a datasource, I simply access the values I need when the user clicks a save button.

I need to add autocomplete functionality to one of the columns in this grid, easily achieved with an asp.net textbox and ajaxtoolkit autocomplete extender.

Problem is, I must do everything I can to avoid postbacks, and if I add rows client side, the templated column does not work.

Any idea how can I achieve this? And if I must do a trip back to the server, how to minimize them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first time I ask a question and doesn't get an inmediate answer. I am going to describe what I am going to do just for anyone with the same problem or just in case anyone with a better solution gets to read this.

I am simply going to wrap the WebGrid in a UpdatePanel, and call the igtbl_doPostBack() at the right times and let the panel handle the thing for me.

It is still a postback, but it saves me from a lot of trouble, and its not so bad as you can´t see the flashbacks of a full postback.